# In Intgeration from Salesforce to Snowflake , how long can i make authorization code to be used

Tags: api, salesforce, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, integration, apex

In Integration from Salesforce to Snowflake , how long can I make authorization code to be used .I am not worried about access token or refresh token .The first stage authorization code .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you are having "Authorization_Code" OAuth grant-flow and the authorization code generated as the first step for this is the one which you are looking for.

Ideally it is 5 minutes but can be set lower value as well. More details regarding this are provided here:

[https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/authorization/the-authorization-response/#:~:text=The%20authorization%20code%20must%20expire,the%20codes%20should%20be%20documented](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/authorization/the-authorization-response/#:%7E:text=The%20authorization%20code%20must%20expire,the%20codes%20should%20be%20documented).

[When should an OAuth authorization code expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55138644/when-should-an-oauth-authorization-code-expire)